# Identifying system reserved drive using DeviceIoControl function in C++

Tags: c++, deviceiocontrol

I am trying to identify if a drive is system reserved drive(`PhysicalDrive0` or `C-Drive`) using `DeviceIoControl` function. However my code is always returning true for all the drives.

```
HANDLE hDevice;               // handle to the drive to be examined
BOOL bResult;                 // results flag
DWORD junk;                   // discard results

PARTITION_INFORMATION_MBR *pdg

hDevice = CreateFile(TEXT("\\\\.\\C:"), GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FILE_SHARE_READ |
        FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);


bResult = DeviceIoControl(
            hDevice,                        // device to be queried
            IOCTL_DISK_GET_PARTITION_INFO_EX,  // operation to perform
            NULL, 0,                        // no input buffer
            pdg, sizeof(*pdg),              // output buffer
            &junk,                          // # bytes returned
            (LPOVERLAPPED) NULL             // synchronous I/O
        );
```

- `bResult` isalways returning 0, indicating that the function succeeded.
- Even `pdg->PartitionType` has junk information and not returning `true`.

Comment: You might want to take a closer look: *Return value:
If the operation completes successfully, the return value is nonzero.
If the operation fails or is pending, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call GetLastError.*

Comment: DeviceIoControl successfully retrieved the partition info and it is (stored in your `PARTITION_INFORMATION_EX` structure) therefore it returned 0 (success).   You need to now look at your `PARTITION_INFORMATION_EX` structure and see if the information you requested is there or not.

Answer (score 0):

> bResult isalways returning 0, indicating that the function succeeded.

Plain wrong, [the documentation states](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/aa363216(v=vs.85).aspx) If the operation completes successfully, the return value is nonzero. Many things could be wrong, at least your parameters are not right and `GetLastError` would have returned `ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER`:

---

You're giving `DeviceIoControl` a uninitialized pointer, but it expects that `pdg` points to a buffer, in this case, with the size of a pointer to `PARTITION_INFORMATION_MBR`. Dereferencing wild pointers invokes undefined behavior. Also, according to [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/aa365179(v=vs.85).aspx) `DeviceIoControl` with `OCTL_DISK_GET_PARTITION_INFO` awaits a `PARTITION_INFORMATION_EX` structure so

---

Change

```
PARTITION_INFORMATION_MBR *pdg(;)
```

to

```
PARTITION_INFORMATION_EX pdg;
```

So you got a structure with automatic storage, for which you can give `DeviceIoControl` a temporary pointer to it, with the `&` operator.

```
bResult = DeviceIoControl(
        hDevice,                        // device to be queried
        IOCTL_DISK_GET_PARTITION_INFO_EX,  // operation to perform
        NULL, 0,                        // no input buffer
        &pdg, sizeof(pdg),              // output buffer
        &junk,                          // # bytes returned
        (LPOVERLAPPED) NULL             // synchronous I/O
    );
```