# Retrieve the partition number of BootMgr on Windows Vista and later

Tags: windows, hard-drive, bootloader

I need to map Boot Manager to a partition number:

```
 Manufacturer Recovery partition = Partition 0 
 Boot manager = Partition 1
 C:\ = Partition 2
 D:\ = Partition 3
```

For mounted partitions, like C:\ or D:\, I use [IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_DEVICE_NUMBER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb968800%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to retrieve partition numbers.

Now I would like to do something similar to get the number of the Windows Boot Manager. I can't assume that the BootMgr is the 100 MB partition or the previous to the System partition.

I have had a look to [IOCTLs related to disk geometry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363987%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but I didn't find anything useful. I need to distinguish the Boot Manager partition from, let's say, a 100 MB manufacturer Recovery partition.

BCDEDIT.exe tool shows the info needed;

```
Identificador           {bootmgr}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume1
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  es-ES
inherit                 {globalsettings}
extendedinput           Yes
default                 {current}
resumeobject            {5586dd33-361b-11e0-8df8-0018716eb820}
displayorder            {current}
toolsdisplayorder       {memdiag}
timeout                 30
customactions           0x1000085000001
                        0x5400000f
custom:5400000f         {1f473c8f-0c00-11e1-898d-78acc0c157a7}
```

I'm developing my app in C and therefore [the BCDEDIT approach implies to include a COM/WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa362677%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) dependency to my relatively simple application.

Please, note that I'm talking about opening a handle to BootMgr partition using "\Device\HarddiskVolume1" retrieved through WMI and then using IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_DEVICE_NUMBER:

```
hHandle = CreateFile ("\\\\?\\GLOBALROOT\\Device\\HarddiskVolume1", 
                        GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE,
                        FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE, 
                        NULL, 
                        OPEN_EXISTING, 
                        FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                        NULL);

if ( hHandle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
{
    VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS diskExtents;
    DWORD dwSize;
    BOOL iRes;

    iRes = DeviceIoControl(hHandle,
                            IOCTL_VOLUME_GET_VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS,
                            NULL,
                            0,
                            (LPVOID) &diskExtents,
                            (DWORD) sizeof(diskExtents),
                            (LPDWORD) &dwSize,
                            NULL);

    if (iRes)
    {
        STORAGE_DEVICE_NUMBER deviceNumber;
        DWORD bytesReturned =  0;

        iRes = DeviceIoControl(hHandle, 
                        IOCTL_STORAGE_GET_DEVICE_NUMBER, 
                        NULL, 
                        0, 
                        &deviceNumber, 
                        sizeof(deviceNumber), 
                        &bytesReturned, NULL);
```

Any ideas for a simpler workaround?

Comment: I didnt see in BCDEdit output exactly what you want.

Comment: Well, the output says {bootmgr} is partition \Device\HarddiskVolume1. Considering that in this machine C: is \Device\HarddiskVolume2 and D: is \Device\HarddiskVolume3... is a kind of partition enumartion. Don't think so?

Comment: And If C: is \Device\HarddiskVolume1 ? Maybe this question helps you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12488337/identifying-system-reserved-drive-using-deviceiocontrol-function-in-c

Comment: Do you really think that bootmgr have own partition ???

Comment: I am not saying that harcoding "\Device\HarddiskVolume1" is a solution. I'm just saying volume numeration can help to identify BootMgr partition number. And yes, Boot Manager in Vista and post Windows version can have the Boot Manager in a separate partition.

Comment: Really ????? Bootmgr.exe is located in the root of the system partition !!!

Comment: You are right. When I'm saying that this partition contains the Boot Manager I'm not being precise. I have configured Grub to boot from this 100 MB partition and it works... so I'm confused now.

Comment: Again, IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_LAYOUT_EX is your right direction. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the system volume (where Windows booted and also where bootmgr reside) by looking in the registry:  `HKLM\SYSTEM\Setup\SystemPartition`.  This will contain a name like **\Device\HardDiskVolume1**.

On a  disk formatted by Windows 7 setup, this corresponds to the 100MB partition that starts before the partition that contains drive C:.  On Windows 7, the big partition that contains drive C: is **\Device\HardDiskVolume2**.

Comment: You saved my day... I ran into bcdedit errors reporting it couldn't find the system partition. I think this does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is too late, but this info can help someone;

You may try to find BootIndicator partition by sending IOCTL code such as `PARTITION_INFORMATION_EX` for real solution.