# Identify System reserved partition

Tags: c, windows, system, driver, volume

I am working on an upper volume filter driver using diskperf as base. Can any one tell me how can I identify a system reserved partition at boot time?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15361617/retrieve-the-partition-number-of-bootmgr-on-windows-vista-and-later/15366989#15366989

Comment: Hi, @Xearinox, Thanks for your reply, the link that you provided didn't helped. I want to find the "system reserved partition" when the system is booting, through code in 'C' as I am working on an upper volume filter driver.

Comment: I understand, but what is problem?

Comment: Read registry value from filter.

Comment: You first need to define what *exactly* you mean by "system reserved partition".  The bootable partition created during Windows setup?  The currently active partition?  The partition whose *name* is "System Reserved"?  Something else?

Comment: Hi @Harry Johnston, I want to identify the partition whose name is "System Reserved" which occupies around 100Mb.

Comment: I believe that sending a `IOCTL_DISK_GET_PARTITION_INFO_EX` request down the volume stack will give you information about the partition associated with that volume (or perhaps all partitions on the drive, the documentation is a bit unclear).  Alternatively, `IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_LAYOUT_EX` should give you information about all the partitions on the drive, in addition to other information about the drive itself.